# How to update an array in Python based on another array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays in Python.

`array1` looks like this:

```
[[ 59.13425446  85.62345123]
 [ 59.4981575   87.67746735]
 [ 57.4234575   83.34333335]]
```

`array2` looks like this:

```
[[ 255  255]
 [ 1.0   255]
 [ 255   1.0]]
```

I want to update `array1`. For every value in `array2` that equals `1.0`, I want to update `array1` with a value of `0.0`. In the end it should look like this:

```
[[ 59.13425446  85.62345123]
 [ 0.0   87.67746735]
 [ 57.4234575   0.0]]
```

How can I do this in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
array1[array2 == 1] = 0
```

Comment: This looks muuuuch cleaner than mine but didnt seem to work. The output was [0, [59.4981575, 87.67746735], [57.4234575, 83.34333335]]. Did you get something else?

Comment: @Jas are you using (numpy) arrays or lists?

Comment: @Jas This method doesn't work for regular Python lists. `array2 == 1` returns just `False` if `array2` is a list. With numpy arrays, the expression evaluates to an array of bools, which are then used as indexes for the assignment.